# box-ios-sdk authentication error

Tags: ios, box

I follow the instruction to setup and integrate my project thou pods, everything went fine.

till i use the following code, which suppose to show the log in screen.

```
BOXContentClient *contentClient = [BOXContentClient defaultClient];
[contentClient authenticateWithCompletionBlock:^(BOXUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        if ([error.domain isEqualToString:BOXContentSDKErrorDomain] && error.code == BOXContentSDKAPIUserCancelledError) {
            BOXLog(@"Authentication was cancelled, please try again.");
        } else {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                                message:@"Login failed, please try again"
                                                               delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            [alertView show];
        }
    } else {
        BOXContentClient *tmpClient = [BOXContentClient clientForUser:user];
    }
}];
```

However I received the following error

> 2015-07-21 17:06:27.290 Sendr[83352:747338] -[BOXContentClient authenticateWithCompletionBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7be773e0

2015-07-21 17:06:27.295 Sendr[83352:747338] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BOXContentClient authenticateWithCompletionBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7be773e0'

*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0064e746 __exceptionPreprocess + 182

```
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x03030a97 objc_exception_throw + 44

2   CoreFoundation                      0x00656705 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277

3   CoreFoundation                      0x0059d287 ___forwarding___ + 1047

4   CoreFoundation                      0x0059ce4e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14

5   Sendr                               0x0002a1bc -[SendrAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 156

6   UIKit                               0x0141df87 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 287

7   UIKit                               0x0141ed71 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2938

8   UIKit                               0x014223d2 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1639

9   UIKit                               0x0143b8ee __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 59

10  UIKit                               0x01420ffa -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 155

11  FrontBoardServices                  0x08358c9e __37-[FBSWorkspace clientEndTransaction:]_block_invoke_2 + 71

12  FrontBoardServices                  0x0835872f __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 54

13  FrontBoardServices                  0x0836ad7c __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 30

14  CoreFoundation                      0x00570050 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16

15  CoreFoundation                      0x00565963 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 195

16  CoreFoundation                      0x005657bb __CFRunLoopRun + 2715

17  CoreFoundation                      0x00564a5b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443

18  CoreFoundation                      0x0056488b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
19  UIKit                               0x014209b2 -[UIApplication _run] + 571

20  UIKit                               0x014240b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526

21  Sendr                               0x0002a0f9 main + 121
22  libdyld.dylib                       0x03450ac9 start + 1
23  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1)libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I feel like this is more or less a setup issue, but I cannot find anymore documentation. (everything works fine on SDKSample) ...help please!

Answer (score 3):

Issue resolved! so at the end, this issue is caused by an installing issue with cocoapods.

once added $(inherited) in build settings under Other linker flags. the problem went away.

Comment: I fixed it by adding `-ObjC` in `Other linker flags`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the method signature and see if anything is missing or the proper header needs to be imported.

For example, the sample code on Box has a second parameter.

Like this:

```
[contentClient authenticateWithCompletionBlock:^(BOXUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        if ([error.domain isEqualToString:BOXContentSDKErrorDomain] && error.code == BOXContentSDKAPIUserCancelledError) {
            BOXLog(@"Authentication was cancelled, please try again.");
        } else {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                                message:@"Login failed, please try again"
                                                               delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            [alertView show];
        }
    } else {
        BOXContentClient *tmpClient = [BOXContentClient clientForUser:user];
    }
} cancelBlock:nil];
```

Comment: i doubt it, based on the behavior in the sample(provided by box), that code can go anywhere (like first line in applicationdidfinish in appdelgate) and work..

Comment: Sorry I don't mean the code is in the wrong place, but it may be called incorrectly.  Unrecognized selector means the method is not valid.  So first thing is you should check to make sure that you are calling it correctly.

Comment: so this issue is resolved, apparently this issue is caused by an issue when installing box-ios-sdk though cocoapods.

Comment: What sort of issue via cocoapods? Incorrect SDK version?

Comment: not entirely sure, but i think it has something to do with the cocoapods either failed to update the build setting, or that build setting was suppose to be update manually.